# Passing List to subprocess.run

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, subprocess

i've got a script, that contains a list - the list is just some args that I want to pass to `subprocess.run` like this

```
commands = ["bash command 1", "bash command 2",..]
```

here is my code

```
commands = ["bash command 1", "bash command 2",..]
process = subprocess.run([commands], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
```

how can I pass a list to my subprocess.run?

this is the Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./retesting.py", line 18, in <module>
    process = subprocess.run([commands], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 383, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1221, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

I Have no idea what I'm doing wrong and I tried all sorts of things, so I'd appreciate really any help

Comment: Why do you define your commands as a ``set``(using ``{}``) when you need a list (using ``[]``)?

Comment: sorry that was actually a mistake i had while typing out the question, edited my question

Comment: Simply drop the ``[]`` from ``.run([commands],``.

Comment: @Rakesh thanks for the feedback, I changed my code to what you suggested and i dont get any errors, only now it seems to pass the first argument to bash and ignores the rest. what could i be doing wrong? thanks a lot!

Comment: Are these *separate* commands, as in ``["cd", "ls", "rm"]``, or a command and arguments, as in ``["ls", "-l", "-a"]``?

Comment: @skdadle Do **not**  use `shell=True`. It changes how the command list is interpreted.

Comment: okay, so when i use `list(commands)` it works, i also works when dropping the `[ ]`, i get the same result there, it just passes the first string of my list to bash. They're separate commands, hope I didn't confuse you
@MisterMiyagi my arguments are basically `"cd ~/app cli && bash app"` with parameters that specify username and password to run that app but i have them all in one string like this `"cd ~/app cli && bash app -- email some-email --password somepassword .. "`

Comment: @skdadle Leaving aside that you should do the ``cd`` and ``&&`` in Python, how do you know the command failed or ignored your input? Does it throw or log an error?

Answer (score 10):

Before using `shell=True` you have to understand what it does. Take [the documentation for `Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen). It states:

> The `shell` argument (which defaults to `False`) specifies whether to use
>   the shell as the program to execute. **If shell is `True`, it is
>   recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence.**
>
> On Unix with `shell=True`, the shell defaults to `/bin/sh`. If `args` is a
>   string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell.
>   This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be
>   when typed at the shell prompt. This includes, for example, quoting or
>   backslash escaping filenames with spaces in them. **If `args` is a
>   sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any
>   additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell
>   itself.** That is to say, `Popen` does the equivalent of:
>
> ```
> Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])
> ```
>
> On Windows with
>   `shell=True`, the `COMSPEC` environment variable specifies the default
>   shell. The only time you need to specify `shell=True` on Windows is when
>   the command you wish to execute is built into the shell (e.g. `dir` or
>   `copy`). You do not need `shell=True` to run a batch file or console-based
>   executable.

There is no way to execute a sequence of commands in one go, what you are doing is executing the first command and all other commands as passed *when spawning the shell as options to that shell*.

You want to do this instead:

```
for command in commands:
    subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
```

Alternatively: you want to execute the sequence of commands as a single script:

```
subprocess.run(';'.join(commands), shell=True)
```

This said: if the commands inside command are only executables you should really avoid using `shell=True` and use `shlex.split` to provide the parsed argument list. If you need to specify the directory where the command should be executed you can use the `cwd` argument to `Popen` (or any similar function).

In your case you want something like:

```
import os, subprocess

subprocess.run(['app', '--email', 'some-email', '--password', 'somepassword'], cwd=os.path.expanduser('~/app-cli'))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer!, but now i get an invalid syntax error in my first string of my list, but when i pass it normally as one argument like this `subprocess.run("the exact same string like my first one in the list", shell = true)`  it works, any ideas?

Comment: in your answer u show me how to pass one argument to subprocess.run, cant I pass a sequence/list of arguments that it executes one after the other?

Comment: @skdadle  `subprocess.run` always execute **one** thing. This thing can either be an executable (when `shell=False`), in which case the argument is a list of strings that specifies the command line, or it can execute a single *shell script* (when `shell=True`). A shell script can be composed of multiple shell commands. In UNIX style shells you can separate multiple commands using `;` (or newlines). As I said: I think you should avoid `shell=True` or executing multiple commands if you can. If you have more issue please edit your question to include the errors you get.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, i tried your solution - with `(';'.join(commands), shell = True)` but i got an invalid syntax error, I'm confused because each command is enclosed in double quotes, separated by a comma, and i thought we should write our command exactly like how we would write it in shell.. 

i cant use the second answer you suggested because i have a larger number of commands and i don't want to type each one in separately , that's also why i wanted to use a list in the first place, also i need shell = true because im not running executables. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @skdadle Without providing the exact list of commands you want to run we have to way of knowing why you get a syntax error. If you want better answers you should try to provide as much information as possible in your question. If you give generic information you will receive generic answers. Sometimes that's enough, other times they are suboptimal.